# postgres - ERROR: operator does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Again, I have a function that works fine locally, but moving it online yields a big fat error... Taking a cue from a response in which someone had pointed out the number of arguments I was passing wasn't accurate, I double-checked in this situation to be certain that I am passing 5 arguments to the function itself...

```
Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

The query is this:

```
BEGIN; SELECT zip_proximity_sum('zc',                                                                                                                                                                  
    (SELECT g.lat FROM geocoded g                                                                                                                                                                              
    LEFT JOIN masterfile m ON g.recordid = m.id                                                                                                                                                                
    WHERE m.zip = '10050' ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 1),                                                                                                                                                             
    (SELECT g.lon FROM geocoded g                                                                                                                                                                              
    LEFT JOIN masterfile m ON g.recordid = m.id                                                                                                                                                                
    WHERE m.zip = '10050' ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 1),                                                                                                                                                             
    (SELECT m.zip FROM geocoded g                                                                                                                                                                              
    LEFT JOIN masterfile m ON g.recordid = m.id                                                                                                                                                                
    WHERE m.zip = '10050' ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 1)                                                                                                                                                              
    ,10);
```

The PG function is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip_proximity_sum(refcursor, numeric, numeric, character, numeric)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$ 
    BEGIN 

        OPEN $1 FOR 
            SELECT r.zip, point($2,$3) <@> point(g.lat, g.lon) AS distance
            FROM
            geocoded g LEFT JOIN masterfile r ON g.recordid = r.id 
            WHERE (geo_distance( point($2,$3),point(g.lat,g.lon)) < $5)
            ORDER BY r.zip, distance;
        RETURN $1; 
    END; 
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds a bit harsh, but do you actually read the error message???

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? Happening to me. Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`. Restarted PostgreSQL. `[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point`. Maybe an issue with PostgreSQL v11 on Windows?

Answer (score 11):

Here are the exact commands:

```
create extension cube;
create extension earthdistance;
select (point(-0.1277,51.5073) <@> point(-74.006,40.7144)) as distance;

     distance     
------------------
 3461.10547602474
(1 row)
```

Note that `points` are created with **LONGITUDE FIRST**. Per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/earthdistance.html):

> Points are taken as (longitude, latitude) and not vice versa because longitude is closer to the intuitive idea of x-axis and latitude to y-axis.

Which is terrible design... but that's the way it is.

Comment: This doesn't work. Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`. Restarted PostgreSQL. `[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point`. Maybe an issue with PostgreSQL v11 on Windows? Yes Long/Lat in correct order.

Comment: Its not a terrible design, its the default. Postgis by default is Long Lat. We usually talk about x,y, which in this case is Long Lat, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The `<@>` operator is provided by `earthdistance` extension. 
You need to call `create extension earthdistance;` on production database.

- More info about Earthdistance: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html
- Checking available extensions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html

Comment: Yes but it still throws error. Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`. Restarted PostgreSQL. `[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point`. Maybe an issue with PostgreSQL v11 on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create extensions under pg_catalog schema. So that those can be available globally. Please execute below commands:

- drop extension if exists earthdistance;
- drop extension if exists cube;
- create extension cube schema pg_catalog;
- create extension earthdistance schema pg_catalog;

Comment: The question is a little bit old (10 years) so, I don't know if your answer is still relevant.

Comment: This helped me out, thank you for pointing out the schema parameter!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that postgis was properly installed on the online server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify <@> operator like this:

```
OPERATOR(schema.<@>)
```

if the schema in which the extension is created is not listed in search_path:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to solve this problem

1. Run below command two check the extensions (`cube` & `earthdistance`)

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions ORDER BY "name"
```

2. Run the below command if still both extensions (`cube` & `earthdistance`) showing in the list:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

3. create table and insert values

- Create Location Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE location (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    longitude double precision NOT NULL,
    latitude double precision NOT NULL
);
```

- Insert Us Some Data (Sites around #CHA)

```sql
INSERT INTO location(name, latitude, longitude)
VALUES ('SupplyHog HQ', 35.0472780, -85.3071590)
,('Chickamauga Dam', 35.0975557,-85.2197027)
,('Five Points Mtn Biking', 34.851249, -85.423983)
,('Harrison Bay State Park', 35.179631, -85.114359)
,('Mojo Burrito', 35.0094040,-85.3275640)
,('Rock Creek', 35.0556150,-85.2803290);
```

4. Run select query you will get the result

- When creating points, it is `point(long, lat)`

```sql
SELECT *, point(-85.3078294, 35.0609500) <@> point(longitude, latitude)::point as distance 
FROM location
WHERE (point(-85.3078294, 35.0609500) <@> point(longitude, latitude)) < 10
ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of error is the select statement in your stored procedure:

```
SELECT r.zip, point($2,$3) <@> point(g.lat, g.lon) AS distance
                            ^
```

At the marked position an operator is expected, but your operator is either not defined or has other argumet types. Postgres itself only knows of the `<@` and `@>` containment operators. Look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) for their explanation.

Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Unhelpful answer. Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`. Restarted PostgreSQL. `[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point`. Maybe an issue with PostgreSQL v11 on Windows? Yes Lat/Long in correct order (long is first).