# PostgreSQL latitude longitude query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i have `latitude` and `longitude` columns in `location` table in PostgreSQL database,
and I am trying to execute distance query with a PostgreSQL function.

I read this chapter of the manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html

but I think I'm missing something there.

How should I do that? Are there more examples available

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This module is optional and is not installed in the default PostgreSQL instalatlion. You must install it from the contrib directory.

You can use the following function to calculate the approximate distance between coordinates (in miles):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance(lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT) RETURNS FLOAT AS $$
DECLARE                                                   
    x float = 69.1 * (lat2 - lat1);                           
    y float = 69.1 * (lon2 - lon1) * cos(lat1 / 57.3);        
BEGIN                                                     
    RETURN sqrt(x * x + y * y);                               
END  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can you explain the math in here? What 69.1 and 57.3 represent?

Comment: I'd imagine they are constants used to convert latitude and longitude into miles.

Comment: To use KM instead of miles, use constants 111.12 & 92.215 to replace 69.1 & 57.3

Comment: Why is the approach to do this with Postgresql and not with Java for example in a function

Comment: @FernandoPie When there are many rows and the distance is part of the `WHERE` clause, it's faster to let the database filter the results than transfering all the rows to Java first.

Answer (score 59):

Here's another example using the point operator:

**Initial setup** (only need to run once):

```
create extension cube;
create extension earthdistance;
```

And then the query:

```
select (point(-0.1277,51.5073) <@> point(-74.006,40.7144)) as distance;

     distance     
------------------
 3461.10547602474
(1 row)
```

Note that `points` are created with **LONGITUDE FIRST**. Per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html):

> Points are taken as (longitude, latitude) and not vice versa because longitude is closer to the intuitive idea of x-axis and latitude to y-axis.

Which is terrible design... but that's the way it is.

Your output will be in **miles**.

> Gives the distance in statute miles between two points on the Earth's surface.

Comment: Got a vote for being cleaner than the other answer based on `earthdistance`

Comment: "Gives the distance in statute miles between two points on the Earth's surface."

Comment: Do you have to run "create extension" queries each time?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 i've updated the instructions to make it clear that those are for setup and you only need to run them once

Comment: This doesn't work. Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`. Restarted PostgreSQL. `[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point`. Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665786/postgres-error-operator-does-not-exist Maybe an issue with Postgres on Windows?

Comment: @SteveTauber how to implement this with docker and kubernetes? I mean how to add extension with Postgresql being installed in container?

Comment: @0x01Brain I suggest you post this as a new question

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you've installed the earthdistance module correctly, this will give you the distance in miles between two cities. This method uses the simpler point-based earth distances.  Note that the arguments to point() are first longitude, then latitude.

```
create table lat_lon (
  city varchar(50) primary key,
  lat float8 not null,
  lon float8 not null
);

insert into lat_lon values
('London, GB', 51.67234320, 0.14787970),
('New York, NY', 40.91524130, -73.7002720);

select 
  (
  (select point(lon,lat) from lat_lon where city = 'London, GB') <@>
  (select point(lon,lat) from lat_lon where city = 'New York, NY')
  ) as distance_miles

distance_miles
--
3447.58672105301
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is the best way to do it. You just need to run `CREATE EXTENSION cube; CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;` to install earthdistance.

Answer (score 10):

A more accurate version of @strkol's answer, using the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance(
    lat1 double precision,
    lon1 double precision,
    lat2 double precision,
    lon2 double precision)
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    R integer = 6371e3; -- Meters
    rad double precision = 0.01745329252;

    φ1 double precision = lat1 * rad;
    φ2 double precision = lat2 * rad;
    Δφ double precision = (lat2-lat1) * rad;
    Δλ double precision = (lon2-lon1) * rad;

    a double precision = sin(Δφ/2) * sin(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1) * cos(φ2) * sin(Δλ/2) * sin(Δλ/2);
    c double precision = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));    
BEGIN                                                     
    RETURN R * c;        
END  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Input is in degrees (e.g. 52.34273489, 6.23847) and output is in meters.

Comment: I go for this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that using special characters like `Δ` and `λ` is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate Haversine formula, returning miles. ([source](https://gist.github.com/carlzulauf/1724506))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.geodistance(
    latitude1 double precision,
    longitude1 double precision,
    latitude2 double precision,
    longitude2 double precision)
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
SELECT asin(
  sqrt(
    sin(radians($3-$1)/2)^2 +
    sin(radians($4-$2)/2)^2 *
    cos(radians($1)) *
    cos(radians($3))
  )
) * 7926.3352 AS distance;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```