# Get distance between two nearest latitude and longitude

Tags: node.js, postgresql, geolocation, sequelize.js

I want to find a nearest distance between two point. I am creating a ordering based application in which I need to find a nearest distance of customer and provider within a certain range (3km) I am using a postgres as a database and a sequelize as a orm.
I don't want want to use **Haversine formula** in my code is there any way that can I use it

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034636/postgresql-latitude-longitude-query

Comment: use postgis ...